# Wix - Customize Boostrap for Bundle

Tags: wix, installation

I'll explain.

I have a bundle which contains several prerequisites and the **main msi**. During the installation of the **main msi**, there are several custom actions that get executed, I would like to when the user presses cancel in the bundle, to execute a custom action in the **main msi**.

The workflow would be:

- User starts Bundle.exe
- Bundle.exe starts installation of prerequisites
- Bundle.exe starts installation of main msi
- User presses cancel in the Bundle.exe
- Bundle.exe executes custom action in the **main msi**
- The end result will be cancelling whatever custom action the **main    msi** is doing, for example, a thread running doing some stuff to    files

I read about UI customization here: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/wixstdba/wixstdba_customize.html but I don't see how to fire an event from a button. The only thing that I found is this:

```
<Control Id="...>
    <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="MyCustomActionInMainMSI">1</Publish>
</Control>
```

But, **[Control](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/control.html)** can only be a child of Dialog or Billboard, and also none of those are present in the "customtheme.xml".

So, is there a way for me, WITHOUT extending the interface completely using a custom Bootstrapper (custom DLL which implements what I want), to add a Cancel button and firing a custom action **IN the Bundle**?

Comment: Haha... I was totally confused until I hovered over the tag and realized you __weren't__ talking about https://www.wix.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up extending the interface, don't know if it is the most elegant solution, but it works :)